# Why do NSString and NSLog appear to handle %C and %lc (and %S and %ls) differently?

Tags: cocoa, unicode, formatting, printf

Apple's [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) document claims,

> The format specifiers supported by the NSString formatting methods and CFString formatting functions follow the [IEEE printf specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html); … You can also use these format specifiers with the NSLog function.

But, while the `printf` specification defines `%C` as an equivalent for `%lc` and `%S` as an equivalent for `%ls`, only `%C` and `%S` appear to work correctly with `NSLog` and `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]`.

For example, consider the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    unichar str[3];
    str[0] = 63743;
    str[1] = 33;
    str[2] = (unichar)NULL;

    NSLog(@"NSLog");
    NSLog(@"%%S:  %S", str);
    NSLog(@"%%ls: %ls", str);

    NSLog(@"%%C:  %C", str[0]);
    NSLog(@"%%lc: %lc", str[0]);

    NSLog(@"\n");
    NSLog(@"+[NSString stringWithFormat:]");

    NSLog(@"%%S:  %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%S", str]);
    NSLog(@"%%ls: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ls", str]);

    NSLog(@"%%C:  %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", str[0]]);
    NSLog(@"%%lc: %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lc", str[0]]);

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Given the `printf` specification, I would expect each of the above pairs to print the same thing. But, when I run the code, I get the following output:

```
2009-03-20 17:00:13.363 UnicharFormatSpecifierTest[48127:10b] NSLog
2009-03-20 17:00:13.365 UnicharFormatSpecifierTest[48127:10b] %S:  !
2009-03-20 17:00:13.366 UnicharFormatSpecifierTest[48127:10b] %ls: ˇ¯!
2009-03-20 17:00:13.366 UnicharFormatSpecifierTest[48127:10b] %C:  
2009-03-20 17:00:13.367 UnicharFormatSpecifierTest[48127:10b] %lc: 
2009-03-20 17:00:13.367 UnicharFormatSpecifierTest[48127:10b] 
2009-03-20 17:00:13.368 UnicharFormatSpecifierTest[48127:10b] +[NSString stringWithFormat:]
2009-03-20 17:00:13.368 UnicharFormatSpecifierTest[48127:10b] %S:  !
2009-03-20 17:00:13.369 UnicharFormatSpecifierTest[48127:10b] %ls: ˇ¯!
2009-03-20 17:00:13.369 UnicharFormatSpecifierTest[48127:10b] %C:  
2009-03-20 17:00:13.370 UnicharFormatSpecifierTest[48127:10b] %lc:
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Apple's code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Mac OS X, `<machine/_types.h>` defines `wchar_t` as `int`, so it's four bytes (32 bits) on all currently-supported architectures.

As you note, the `printf`(3) manpage defines `%S` as equivalent to `%ls`, which takes a pointer to some `wchar_t` characters (`wchar_t *`).

The Cocoa documentation you linked to (and its CF equivalent), however, does define `%S` separately:

> - `%S`: Null-terminated array of **16-bit** Unicode characters

Emphasis added. Also, the same goes for `%C`.

So, this is not a bug. CF and Cocoa interpret `%S` and `%C` differently from how `printf` and its cousins interpret them. CF and Cocoa treat the character(s) as UTF-16, whereas `printf` (presumably) treats them as UTF-32.

The CF/Cocoa interpretation is more useful when working with Core Services, as some APIs (such as the File Manager) will hand you text as an array of `UniChar`s, not a CFString; as long as you null-terminate that array, you can use it with `%S` to print the string.

Comment: Thanks; that makes a lot of sense! I think I would characterize this as a bug in the documentation, then, because the NSString formatting methods clearly do not follow the printf specification in this case. Does that seem like a fair assessment?

Comment: Moderate bug; it should say something like “…, with a couple of variations”, and mark them in the table. The document does correctly describe CF/Cocoa's interpretations in the table, although it does not flag them as different from printf's definitions.

Comment: That's about how I'd characterize it, as well. Thanks again for the help!