# NSDictionary objectForKey: string issue

Tags: ios, encoding, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have a `NSDictionary` created with data from a web api.

Here is the dictionary logged:

```
{
chapter =     {
    text = "\n  \tAmo\U00cc\U0081s";
};
```

}

When loging `[dict objectForKey:@"chapter"]` looks like this:

```
{
text = "\n  \tAmo\U00cc\U0081s";
```

}

And when logging `[dict objectForKey:@"text"]` I get

```
AmoÌs
```

which is not correct, it should be `Amo\U00cc\U0081s` / `Amós`

It seems to be an encoding problem, but I can't figure it out.
Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NSLog is printing correctly!!!

You can not print Unicode text to log. You have new line, a tab and \U00cc and \U0081 which is converting to some un-readalbe texts.

This is not a bug. CF and Cocoa interpret %S and %C differently from how printf and its cousins interpret them. CF and Cocoa treat the character(s) as UTF-16, whereas printf (presumably) treats them as UTF-32.

The CF/Cocoa interpretation is more useful when working with Core Services, as some APIs (such as the File Manager) will hand you text as an array of UniChars, not a CFString; as long as you null-terminate that array, you can use it with %S to print the string.

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667994/why-do-nsstring-and-nslog-appear-to-handle-c-and-lc-and-s-and-ls-different).

Comment: Yep. You are right. It was an encoding problem on the server side.